# Can I reboot and log back in, without a password, in one command?

Tags: linux, command-line, login, reboot

Can I reboot and log back in without a password, in one command?

Comment: You can hibernate and reboot instead of turning off but you have to have swap.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk can you show me real quick? i think i recall seing a small swap partition. will i have to login manually? i want to automate it. quick shutdown/reboot; login;

Comment: so you can resume your work without missing a beat

Comment: With a password? So you issue one command, this causes the system to reboot, and ask for a password, then you are logged in?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it shouldn't ask for a password in this case. or if it does, then automated, behind the scenes

Comment: thanks for the edit whoever did that

Answer (score 1):

You could tell kernel to reboot instead turning off when hibernating:

```
echo reboot | sudo tee /sys/power/disk
```

Now hibernate using your preferred method, for example:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply     --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower"     /org/freedesktop/UPower     org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

This particular method works without `sudo`. Remember to restore contents of
/sys/power/disk or your machine will keep rebooting when hibernating:

```
echo platform | sudo tee /sys/power/disk
```

Notice that you need to have swap set up in order for hibernation to
work - either on a separate partition or as a swapfile.

Comment: i'm always root. security is not a priority. although i would like to retain basic password login/authentication on the system. however, there is a special case where i need to reeboot and login automatically without having to type the password.

Comment: thanks im impressed by your skill, but i think surely there is a much simpler way, no? i will look further into your suggestions